# Why can't I use class Object in my function

Tags: c++

I have some problems with how my class object works in my program. I have 4 classes: `Student`, `Print`, `Write`, and `Load`.

My code is as follow:

Main:

```
char filename[20];
int choice;
PrintData newPrint;
StoreData writeData;
LoadData readData;
Student a;

a.studentID = 2;
a.studentName = "Michael;
cout << "Please enter output file name: ";
cin >> fileName;
cout << "Enter choice: ";
cin >> choice;
if (choice == 1)
    writeData.StoreStudent(newStudent, numStudent, fileName);
else
    readData.LoadStudent(newStudent, numStudent, fileName);
```

My Student class:

```
class Student{
public:
    int studentID;
    std::string studentName;
};
```

My Print class:

```
#include "Student.h"
void printStudent(Student a);
```

My Store Data class:

```
#include "Student.h"
void StoreData::StoreStudent(Student a, int numStudent, char name[20])
```

Store data.h:

```
class StoreData{
public:
    char outputName;
    void StoreStudent(Student *newStudent, int numStudent, char name[20]);
};
```

and my Load Data class:

```
#include "Student.h"
void LoadData::LoadStudent(Student *newStudent, int &numStudent, char name[20])
```

my LoadData.h:

```
class LoadData{
public:
    void LoadStudent(Student *newStudent, int &numStudent, char name[20]);
};
```

If I do not compile the `LoadData.cpp`, then I can write data to a file and Print data with object from `Print` class.

However, if I compile the `LoadData.cpp`, then I get this error:

```
    error: ‘Student’ has not been declared
       void StoreStudent(Student *newStudent, int numStudent, char name[20]);
    PrintData.h:4:21: error: ‘Student’ has not been declared
       void printStudent(Student *newStudent, int numStudent);

    prototype for ‘void LoadData::LoadStudent(Student*, int&, char*)’ does not match any in class ‘LoadData’
     void LoadData::LoadStudent(Student *newStudent, int &numStudent, char name[20])
```

I can compile my program without any errors if `LoadData.cpp` is not compiled together. I just do not understand this.

My code is much more than this, and it happens to me that I can include a header file of a class, then use that class object very well. However, in some classes, even if I include a header file of another class, I still get an error, as display above, saying that class Object name is not declare in the header file of the class that I want to use.

Can you explain to me why?

Comment: I forgot to add that, but this is just a shorter version of my code so you can ignore that mistake. Let me fix that.

Comment: Are you defining Student in the student.h file? The only single direct cause of that first compiler error is Student isn't declared yet, but  
that itself could be caused by a few common mistakes. If you posted your actual file contents it could help spot e.g. any #include or #ifdef related problems.

Comment: This is hardly a [mcve] that can be copy/pasted and compiled by other people. But, my magic crystal ball debugger is predicting that you probably have a circular reference between your header files. The kind of error you show is something that a circular reference might produce. Break circular references with forward declarations and pointers/references, and also make use of header guards, if you are not already.